# Scopes at functions?

Tags: javascript

```js
function x() {
  var a = 2;
  y();
}

function y() {
  a += 3;
}
x();
//returns a is not defined
```

If i declare a function (y) outside the function (x) where it's been called, why it isn't inherit the outer function's variables and values? There's a way to solve the problem described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `a` is declared as part of the `function x()`. That's why `a` is available only inside `x()`. To solve the problem you have to pass variable `a` as the function parameter:

```js
function x() {
  var a = 2;
  y(a);
}

function y(a) {
  a += 3;
  console.log(a);
}
x();
```

Comment: Even with closure it isn't possible to inherit the variables and values of `x()` without passing the variables of `x()` as the `y()`'s parameter?

Comment: @GergőHorváth, in your code closure is irrelevant.